# AngularJS UIB TypeAhead pass object to form but don't bind back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have a typeahead on each repeating form element, that contains 5 input fields, everything works well when I select results and populate the input fields but however this doen't update the model (source)

The typeahead:

```
<input type="search"
                                       ng-model="product"
                                       ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"
                                       typeahead-editable="true"
                                       typeahead-click-open
                                       typeahead-loading="product_Loading"
                                       typeahead-input-formatter="inputFormatter($model)"
                                       typeahead-min-length="0"
                                       typeahead-select-on-exact="true"
                                       typeahead-no-results="noResults"
                                       typeahead-popup-template-url="/app/directives/typeaheadDefaultTemplate.html"
                                       typeahead-popup-template-new="products"
                                       autocomplete="off"
                                       placeholder="Select product"
                                       uib-typeahead="tyh as tyh.name for tyh in typeahead($viewValue, 'products')"
                                       class="form-control no-border-right">
```

the recipients for the selected element:

```
<input name="qty" type="number" ng-model="product.qty" class="qty form-control text-right" value="1">
<input name="price" type="number" ng-model="product.price" class="price form-control text-right" placeholder="0.00">
<input name="total" value="0.00" disabled type="number" class="total form-control text-right">
```

Comment: what do you mean by updating the model(source) here?

Answer (score 0):

3rd input needs an ng-model attribute.

On the typeahead, the ng-model refers to the search query. If you want to update the product object and have it flow down to the other inputs, you will have to do that programmatically, either on select or on focus.

In your typeahead, update the model to productSearchModel, then add the following attribute

```
typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label, $event); productSearchModel = '';"
```

then add something like this to your controller

```
 $scope.onSelect = function (item, model, label, event) {
    product = model;
};
```

which will fire when a user selects an option.